# Jquery file upload minimal setup for large files

Tags: php, jquery-file-upload

I have a minimal setup for jquery file upload. My purpose is to be able to upload large files up to 10GB. But for now i can upload only 25MB max. When upload is done the code returns name of the file. When i try to upload 6GB on my localhost the progressbar hits 100% but returns a strange number like that "1411637366-99" instead of the filename and there is no file in the upload folder. I did not figured it out.

Also i tried to upload a file with 55MB. When i do that, everything looks normal, returns filename correctly but there is no file in the upload folder again.

[image]

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>jQuery File Upload Example</title>
</head>
<body>
<input id="fileupload" type="file" name="files[]" data-url="server/php/" multiple>
<div id="progress">
    <div class="bar" style="width: 0%; height: 18px; background: green;"></div>
</div>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/vendor/jquery.ui.widget.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.iframe-transport.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.fileupload.js"></script>
<script>
$(function () {
$('#fileupload').fileupload({
    dataType: 'json',
    done: function (e, data) {
        $.each(data.result.files, function (index, file) {
            $('<p/>').text(file.name).appendTo(document.body);
        });
    },
    progressall: function (e, data) {
        var progress = parseInt(data.loaded / data.total * 100, 10);
        $('#progress .bar').css(
            'width',
            progress + '%'
        );
    }
});
});
</script>
</body> 
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your problem is in the PHP and not in the jquery.

in the php ini file you got:

```
; Maximum allowed size for uploaded files.
upload_max_filesize = 40M

; Must be greater than or equal to upload_max_filesize
post_max_size = 40M
```

you should change it to what you wish.

or, if you dont have access to your ini file you can do this on single file [in your case on UploadHandler.pho] with

```
<?php
    ini_set('upload_max_filesize', '10M');
?>
```

Or as you wrote: you can create an .htaccess file with the following:

```
php_value upload_max_filesize 10000M and php_value post_max_size 10000M **and** php_value memory_limit 128M
```

Comment: I can't access to php.ini. Can i do that in UploadHandler.php?

Comment: you can with ini_set('upload_max_filesize', '10M'); on your file.

Comment: Yeap, you are right but ini_set didn't work for me i don't know why. I just create a .htaccess file in the same folder with UploadHandler.php and i put this lines in it `php_value upload_max_filesize 10000M` and `php_value post_max_size 10000M` and `php_value memory_limit 128M` And voila, problem solved! Maybe you can add this .htaccess to your correct answer. Thank you!

Comment: if you can accept my answer it will be great :) (V sign on the left)

Done!